# Ionic App Not Showing Data When Viewed Through DevApp (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ionic-framework, ionic-devapp

I'm working on an ionic app which requires some nodejs backend code to retrieve and push data to database client(**MongoDB**) everything works fine in my local environment but when I try to open my app through Ionic DevApp to test it across ios and android, it does not work and I couldn't find any data being fetched from database.

**View From my local environment**

[image: View From my local environment]

**View From DevApp**

[image: View From DevApp(Iphone)]

I know its due to that DevApp couldn't make a connection to node server `localhost:8080` to fetch data, but is there any workaround for this so that my app can successfully make a request to node server through DevApp and I can view the data.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.